# ¿Cómo utilizar el resultado de una consulta para generar otra consulta más?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Necesito realizar un bucle a partir de los datos consultados previamente.

Usaré de ejemplo una consulta para ventas por tiendas. Primero ejecuto un `query` para conocer las tiendas que tengo disponibles:

```
SELECT A.CodigoAlmacen AS Tienda
FROM ALMACENS AS A

|   Tienda   |
--------------
|  Tienda1   |
|  Tienda2   |  
|  Tienda3   |  
|  Tienda4   |
```

Ahora, a partir de esto, necesitaría traer todas las ventas según cada una de las filas de la consulta anterior, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT V.FechaVenta, V.Total, V.Cliente
FROM VENTAS AS V
WHERE V.Tienda = @CodigoTienda
```

Sé que con un `While` se podría, al igual que con un cursor (aunque su desempeño no sea el más óptimo), pero no encuentro cómo leer los resultados de la primera consulta y armar un bucle a partir de ahí desde la primera fila hasta la última.

Antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque no haces una consulta a la tabla ventas y haces un INNER JOIN con la tabla tienda y como condición especificas que la tienda esté activa o disponible (o el criterio que quieras ponerle).

```
SELECT V.FechaVenta, V.Total, V.Cliente
FROM VENTAS AS V
INNER JOIN ALMACENS AS TIENDA ON V.CodigoAlmacen = TIENDA.Tienda
WHERE TIENDA.id_estado = 1 //Por ejemplo: Activas
```

La otra opción sería con cursor:

```
DECLARE @CodigoTienda INT;
DECLARE CURSOR_TIENDA CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A.CodigoAlmacen FROM ALMACENS
OPEN CURSOR_TIENDA
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_TIENDA INTO @CodigoTienda
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS= 0
BEGIN
    SELECT V.FechaVenta, V.Total, V.Cliente
    FROM VENTAS AS V

    --Recorre cada fila
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_TIENDA INTO @CodigoTienda
END
CLOSE CURSOR_TIENDA;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_TIENDA;
```

Comment: Creo que es importante señalar que utilizar un cursor para esto, es una mala idea que solo generará lentitud en el procesamiento.

Comment: Sí, en mi volada de cabeza, quise complicar las cosas y no me di cuenta que con un simple join podía hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

De hecho, lo único que necesitas es un JOIN. No necesitas realizar bucles, ya que el motor de la base de datos lo hará por ti.

```
SELECT V.Tienda, 
       V.FechaVenta, 
       V.Total, 
       V.Cliente
FROM ALMACENS AS A
JOIN VENTAS AS V ON A.CodigoAlmacen = V.Tienda;
```

Comment: Ciertamente, con un join bastaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usa joins como los ejemplos de arriba, el cursor si funcionará, solo que este consume muchos recursos del equipo y no es muy recomendable usarlos.